# How to run tomcat 7 in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and new for this environment. I have generated my project as war file and put under webapps folder of tomcat 7. But, How to run Apache Tomcat in-order to get result??

Comment: cd $TOMCAT$/bin/startup.sh || sudo service tomcat start

Comment: @RamonBoza: It showing error like                                             bash: cd: $/bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory
tomcat: unrecognized service

Comment: Well it is more about basis, you don't know linux commands from terminal. First of all, you have to move with cd to %TOMCAT_INSTALLATION_FOLDER%/bin, it would be /opt/local/tomcat7/bin and then execute `sudo sh startup.sh`, or if it is configured properly, directly execute `sudo service tomcat start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the solution. Under the `tomcat/bin` folder there will be one file named `startup.sh`. double click it, then it will ask for prompt, give run. for stop the server use `shutdown.sh`. I hope this will help you.

Comment: This did not work for me, but the answer on this link (http://askubuntu.com/questions/475564/how-to-stop-tomcat7-in-ubuntu) works. 
,To start the server type : 
        sudo service tomcat7 start
,To stop the server type : 
        sudo service tomcat7 stop