# how to run tomcat from binaries distributation ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat

I have downloaded Zip Binary Distributions of tomcat from [Tomcat 7 Downloads](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi). Now I want to run it using command prompt on ubuntu OS. so I extract the zip and then move to bin directory. I run the below command.

```
startup.sh
sudo startup.sh
catalina.sh
```

No command is working. Whats wrong in these command. I remember, i used to run catalina start command for linux server but why these command not working for ubuntu or I need to do something else. I also read: '[How to run tomcat 7 in ubuntu 12.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375290/how-to-run-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-12-04)', but not found useful.

Please tell me how to run tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package your project into `war` and move `war` file to `webapps` dir. Then `cd` from terminal to `bin` dir and execute `./catalina.sh run` or `./startup.sh`.

**UPDATE:**

I got it. They have no rights to be executed. Run this command from `bin` dir:

```
chmod +x catalina.sh startup.sh
```

Comment: I am doing same thing but it says command not found, boat ./catalina.sh and ./startup.sh

Comment: I am inside the bin directory of tomcat and using ./. Even it does not show option in suggestion when tab.